# Can't seem to get .html() of <label>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
$('.adsize_click').click(function () {
  $(this).closest('span').toggleClass('ad_active');
  $('.ads_selected').append($(this).closest('label').html());
});
```

I have a bunch of spans like this:

```
<span class="adsize"><input type="checkbox" name="size" value="1" id="size1" class="adsize_click"><label for="size1" class="adsize_click2">Leaderboard</label></span>
```

I want it so when you click on either the `<input>` or `<label>`, the HTML of the `<label>` (in this case, "Leaderboard") would be appended to a `<div>` below.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `closet` to `siblings` in the `append` line:

```
$('.adsize_click').click(function () {
  $(this).closest('span').toggleClass('ad_active');
  $('.ads_selected').append($(this).siblings('label').html());
});
```

Comment: Works beautifully. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking for the class associated with the label, like so?

`$('.adsize_click,.adsize_click2')`...

Answer (score 0):

`closest` returns the first **ancestor** that matches the selector. The label isn't an ancestor of the input.

You are probably looking for:

```
jQuery('.adsize').click(function () { 
    jQuery('.ads_selected').append(jQuery('label', this).html());
});
```